# How to login to website using Python request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, python-requests, bots

```
def login_form(login_url,  passkey):
    html = requests.get(login_url)
    response = requests.post(login_url, data = passkey, cookies = 
    html.cookies)
    return response


passkey = { "username": "pass", "password": "password"}


login_info = login_form('https://www.cpaelites.com/member.php?action=login', 
  passkey)
print(login_info.url)
```

I'm trying to automate my login process on CPAElites. The return URL response is the same with login, but it doesn't show any error. Mine doesn't show any error, but when I print the response URL it shows that I'm still at the current page, which means I was unsuccessful in logging in.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. You just have few words here.

Comment: What do you see on response?

Comment: Also edit and properly indent the code here

Comment: You have to pass rest of the form fields such as 'submit, 'action' etc. as well. if you (your IP) fail to login more than three times then it'll show you a captcha field. in that case, you have to wait a while (for the system to remove the captcha requirement) or pass the correct captcha answer along with the login request.

Comment: @himal Can you clarify or make an example sir

Comment: Why don't' you use `requests.Session` for the cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the credentials in `data`, whereas passing it with the `auth` parameter might work:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
def login_form(login_url,  passkey):
    html = requests.get(login_url)
    response = requests.post(login_url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(passkey['username'], passkey['password']), cookies = html.cookies)
    return response


passkey = { "username": "pass", "password": "password"}


login_info = login_form('https://www.cpaelites.com/member.php?action=login', passkey)
print(login_info.url)
```

Comment: Can you send me any blog, tutorial or link that the OP might be following?

Comment: @Amey Yadav, still the same bro it still show the login_url